# Why doesn't gwt CellTable show all the results?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, user-interface

I get the list of results using rpc call. I sure that result list is correct because when I use dialog box all data is there. But when I put it in CellTable some rows lost. Why does this happen?

```
public void onSuccess(List<List<String>> result) {  
            CellTable<List<String>> bugsTable = new CellTable<List<String>>();
            // Create columns
            TextColumn<List<String>> idColumn = new TextColumn<List<String>>() {
              @Override
              public String getValue(List<String> recordSet) {
                return recordSet.get(0).toString();
              }
            };

            TextColumn<List<String>> idCommitColumn = new TextColumn<List<String>>() {
              @Override
              public String getValue(List<String> recordSet) {
                  return recordSet.get(1).toString();
              }
            };

            TextColumn<List<String>> erMessageColumn = new TextColumn<List<String>>() {
              @Override
              public String getValue(List<String> recordSet) {
                  return recordSet.get(2).toString();
              }
            };

            // Add the columns.
            bugsTable.addColumn(idColumn, "ID");
            bugsTable.addColumn(idCommitColumn, "ID commit");
            bugsTable.addColumn(erMessageColumn, "Message");

            // Set the total row count. This isn't strictly necessary, but it affects
            // paging calculations, so its good habit to keep the row count up to date.
            bugsTable.setRowCount(result.size(), true);

            // Push the data into the widget.
            bugsTable.setRowData(0, result);
            tabP.add(bugsTable, "bugs");
            RootPanel.get("loadingbarImg").setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The default `ProvidesKey` (`SimpleKeyProvider`) uses objects themselves as keys, so their `equals()` and `hashCode()` are used. The `java.util.List` contract defines the `equals()` and `hashCode()` behaviors, and mandates that two lists with the same items will be `equals()` and have the same `hashCode()`, so if you have some identical rows in your list, it could be a problem.

Solution: don't use `List<String>` for your rows, define a specific row class instead.